# Sqlite in PCl with encryption and password protection

Tags: c#, wpf, sqlite, portable-class-library, password-encryption

I am developing an application that requires MVVM implementation and will be used for WPF, win phone and win 8.
So my approach is to use Sqlite in PCL to create data layer. But if I do google than there are lots of article containing complicated implementations. 
Somewhere I found SqLitePCL and able to run it via PCl and WPF, but now I struck in  encrption and password protection.
Can anyone suggest me the best and easy way.